# Split string in Javascript across 2 fields

Tags: javascript

I have the following script that inserts the value of `name` into the hidden field `first_name` when I focus out the input field. Is it possible if I enter more than one name in the `name` field that everything after the space is moved to `last_name`?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input").focusout(function(){
        var first_name = $(this).val();
     $('input#first_name').val(first_name);
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div style="border: 1px solid black;padding:10px;">
  Name: <input id="name" name="name" autocomplete="off">
 <input type="hidden" id="first_name" name="first_name" autocomplete="off"><br>
 <input type="hidden" id="last_name" name="last_name" autocomplete="off">
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: _“Is it possible if I enter more than one name in the name field that everything after the space is moved to last_name?”_ - Why would you want to do that, the last name of John Fitzgerald Kennedy is not “Fitzgerald Kennedy” …

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input").focusout(function(){
        // splitting the value by space which returns an array
        let temp = $(this).val().trim().split(" "); 
        // the firstr value as first name and removing it from array 
        let first_name = temp.shift();
        // Joining the remaining values by space and setting it as second name 
        let last_name = temp.join(" ");
     $('input#first_name').val(first_name);
      $('input#last_name').val(last_name);
      temp
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div style="border: 1px solid black;padding:10px;">
  Name: <input id="name" name="name" autocomplete="off">
 <input type="hidden" id="first_name" name="first_name" autocomplete="off"><br>
 <input type="hidden" id="last_name" name="last_name" autocomplete="off">
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @michaelmcgurk - Glad to help you!

Answer (score 1):

try this simple thing just split it with space which returns array

```
 $( "#name" ).change(function() {
      var name = $("#name").val();

      var fname = name.substr(0, name.indexOf(' '));
      var lname = name.substr(name.indexOf(' ') + 1);        

      $("first_name").val(fname);
      $("last_name").val(lname);
    });
```

Comment: It will fail to collect anything after the second word

Comment: sorry its late bbut i have updated my answer try this

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a split once function but you could do this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("input").focusout(function() {
        var names = $(this).val().split(" ");
        var firstName = names.shift();
        var lastName = names.join(" ")
        $('input#first_name').val(firstName);
        $('input#last_name').val(lastName);
      });
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>

  <div style="border: 1px solid black;padding:10px;">
    Name: <input id="name" name="name" autocomplete="off">
    <input type="hidden" id="first_name" name="first_name" autocomplete="off"><br>
    <input type="hidden" id="last_name" name="last_name" autocomplete="off">
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This almost works, however first_name value is `[object HTMLInputElement]`

Comment: I had a typo, fixed that

Answer (score 1):

`String#substr` and `String#indexOf` could be used to get string before first space and after first space.

Note: For the sake of demo, I have kept hidden inputs as `text`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("input#name").blur(function() {
    var name = $(this).val();


    var fname = name.substr(0, name.indexOf(' '));
    var lname = name.substr(name.indexOf(' ') + 1);
    $('input#first_name').val(fname);
    $('input#last_name').val(lname);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="border: 1px solid black;padding:10px;">
  Name: <input id="name" name="name" autocomplete="off">
  <input type="text" id="first_name" name="first_name" autocomplete="off"><br>
  <input type="text" id="last_name" name="last_name" autocomplete="off">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `split(/\s+/)` which will create a array of words that you will input in the input box then set the `first_name` with the first element of array and rest all the other words will go into the `last_name`:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("input").focusout(function() {
    var nameArr = $(this).val().split(/\s+/);
    var first_name = nameArr[0];
    //remove first name
    nameArr.shift();
    var last_name = nameArr.join(' ');
    $('#first_name').val(first_name);
    $('#last_name').val(last_name);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div style="border: 1px solid black;padding:10px;">
  Name: <input id="name" name="name" autocomplete="off">
  <input type="hidden" id="first_name" name="first_name" autocomplete="off"><br>
  <input type="hidden" id="last_name" name="last_name" autocomplete="off">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
$(function() {
  $("#name").on('input', function() {
    var parts = $.trim($(this).val()).split(/\s+/); /* break apart on whitespaces */
    $('#first_name').val(parts.shift()); /* get the first word */
    $('#last_name').val(parts.join(' ')); /* join the rest with space */
  });
});
```